# How to insert multiple records

Tags: php, sql, cakephp-2.0

I am a new cake php developer.I am trying to insert multiple record but i cant.My table Structure is given below:
Table Name : 
agents

```
==============================================  
 id | Contact |  Name  |  email_add  | Address
==============================================
```

Controller Code :

```
public function send_money()
    {
         $this->layout='agent';
         $this->Agent->create();
         $this->Agent->set($this->data);

         if(empty($this->data) == false)
            {
                    if($this->Agent->save($this->data))
                    {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('Information Added Successfully.');
                        $this->redirect('send_money');
                    }

            }
            else
            {
                $this->set('errors', $this->Agent->invalidFields());    
            }
    }
```

Model Code Is :

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Admin Login Model
 *
 */
 class Agent extends AppModel
 {
    public $name='Agent';
    public $usetables='agents';

    public $validate = array(

    'contact' => array(
    'contact_not_empty' => array(
        'rule' => 'notEmpty',
        'message' => 'Please Give Contact No',
        'last' => true
        ),
    ),

      'name' =>array(
      'rule' => 'notEmpty', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
      'allowEmpty' => false,
      'message'    => 'Please Enter Name.'
    ),

    'email_add' => array(
            'email_add' => array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'message' => 'Please Enter Valid Email',
            'last' => true
    )),



    );

 }
```

?>

Its not possible to insert records with this code.What should I do?

Comment: I have only one table named agents.I want to save the record twice at a time in this table.What should i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me explain everything.

First of all your html form must be looks like following.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User'); ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('User.0.address',array
            (
                'div'   => null,
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'span required'
            ));
        ?>

        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('User.1.address',array
            (
                'div'   => null,
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'span required'
            ));
        ?>

        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('User.2.address',array
            (
                'div'   => null,
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'span required'
            ));
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" >
    </td>
</tr>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

As you can see to save many record at same time using cakephp you must define it as above it will parse input fields as array this is **cakephp convention**.

I mean `User.0.address for first array element`

`User.1.address for second array element`

`User.2.address for third array element` and so on.

Now.

**In Controller file.**

```
<?php
    function add()
    {
        $this->User->saveAll($this->data['User']);
    }
```

And yes here you are done saving multiple record at same time.

**I just gave you how cakephp works all you need to do is set above hint as per your need.**

Best of luck...

Cheers...

Feel Free to ask... :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Its working,Now i am able to insert multiple reord.But my model code for field validation is not working.Can you please tell me what would be the model code for validation....

Comment: try $this->User->saveAll($this->data['User'], array('validate' => 'only'));

Comment: $this->Agent->saveAll($this->data['Agent'], array('validate' => 'only')); I tried this code but its not working.I just want to validate my field according to my model....

Comment: not working.??? But as per my personal experience with cake this doesn't needed if validation are defined perfectly in model..cake automatically validate multiple fields with same name anyways....so look into model code..

Comment: I am a New Cake php Developer.Given Above is my Model Code.I cant findout what the fault in my mopdel.Can you please help me by checking my model.

Comment: echo $this->Form->input('User.0.address',array
            (
                'div'   => null,
                'label' => false,
                'class' => 'span required'
            ));From this code if i remove zero i.e 'User.0.address' to 'User.address' that time my model working perfectly.Is there any solution??????

Comment: what is ur code can you please update question with latest model controller and view code..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868147/cake-php-model-validation-not-working.Please check this url.I write this new updated code in this link.Thnxs for ur help

Answer (score 3):

Try this saveall() in your query except save, hope this helps

```
 if($this->Agent->saveall($this->data))
```

Let me know if it work.

Comment: I tried it before.It only inserted last record.its not working

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
php echo $this->Form->create('Agents', array('action' => 'send_money'));?>
```

should be replaced with

```
php echo $this->Form->create('Agent', array('action' => 'send_money'));?>
```

and use saveall() in place of save.