# Cake php Model Validation Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I want insert record in a table.For this i have model,view and controller.Everything in my code is working perfectly but my model code for validation not showing any validation message.What should i do?I am giving below the code :

My Controller Code :

```
    public function send_money()
        {

         $this->layout='agent';
         $this->Agent->create();
         $this->Agent->set($this->data);

           if(empty($this->data) == false)
            {
                //$this->Agent->saveAll($this->data['Agent'], array('validate' => 'only')); //This code Id New
                $this->Agent->saveAll($this->data['Agent']);
                $this->Session->setFlash('Information Added Successfully.');
                $this->redirect('send_money');

            }
            else
            {
                $this->set('errors', $this->Agent->invalidFields());    
            }

        }

And My Model Code is :



    App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
    /**
     * Admin Login Model
     *
     */
     class Agent extends AppModel
     {
        public $name='Agent';
        public $usetables='agents';

        public $validate = array(

         'contact' =>array(
          'rule' => 'notEmpty', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
          'allowEmpty' => false,
          'message'    => 'Please Enter Contact No.'
        ),
         'name' =>array(
          'rule' => 'notEmpty', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
          'allowEmpty' => false,
          'message'    => 'Please Enter Name.'
        ),

         'email_add' =>array(
          'rule' => 'email', // or: array('ruleName', 'param1', 'param2' ...)
          'allowEmpty' => false,
          'message'    => 'Please Enter Valid Email.'
        ),
        );

     }
```

Comment: create('Agents' replace it with create('Agent'

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$this->Form->create('Agents',
```

to

```
$this->Form->create('Agent',
```

As your model name is `Agent` not `Agents`
See here: [Model Validation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your controller:

```
if($this->Agent->validates($this->data)) {
```

Instead of:

```
if(empty($this->data) == false)
```

Comment: After place this code in my controller no page will be displayed.The error message is like :  The page isn't redirecting properly,Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete..If if remove $this->redirect('send_money');its working but showing 3 warning like : 1.Undefined index: Agent [APP\Controller\AgentsController.php, line 74] 2.array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given [CORE\Cake\Model\Model.php, line 2035]

Comment: And the third warning is Argument 1 passed to Hash::numeric() must be an array, null given, called in C:\wamp\www\astha\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php on line 2035 and defined [CORE\Cake\Utility\Hash.php, line 618] And my flash message displaying automatically.What should i do?

Comment: Do you have $uses = array('Agent'); as a member of your controller?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 public function send_money()
    {

     $this->layout='agent';
     $this->Agent->create();
     $this->Agent->set($this->data);

       if($this->Agent->saveAll($this->data['Agent'])) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Information Added Successfully.');
            $this->redirect('send_money');
        }
        else {
            $this->set('errors', $this->Agent->invalidFields());    
        }

    }
```

Note : to log the error validation use this `debug($this->Agent->validationErrors);`.