# Update multiple model through a single form

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey guys please help me in this I want to **Update** two tables data through a single form but the data is updating only in a single table and inserting in second table instead of updating the existing record. Here is my code--

**View file:**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Question');
echo $this->Form->input('question');
foreach (range(0,2) as $index) 
{
  echo $this->Form->input('Option.'.$index.'.poll_options');
}
echo $this->Form->input('id',array('type'=>'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Poll');
```

**Controller file:**

```
$data=$this->Question->findById($id);
if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))
{
   if($this->Question->saveAll($this->request->data))
   {
      $this->Session->setFlash('Question has been updated');
      $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
   }
   else
   {
      $this->Session->setFlash('Question has not been updated');
   }
}
if(!$this->request->data) 
{
   $this->request->data=$data;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831307/how-to-insert-multiple-records/14831717#14831717

Comment: that is the code of inserting into database..i want to update fields instead of adding...

Comment: its not a major difference in cakephp just read data and pass id in hidden then cakephp will do update for you...i can't see hidden id created by u

Comment: yes i have passed id as hidden but still in second table it is inserting the record and not updating....updating only in 1st table...

Comment: yes it will update second table because you did not passed second table record ids...are not u..???

Comment: check my view file again..i updated my code..added hidden id..i passed this but still getting the same..

Comment: it will still not work because you need to pass Options id not a question id...understand..?

Comment: there are 4 options...how to pass all 4 options' id?? there is a question id associated to them..so shouldn't i update the options by that foreign key of question id???

Comment: okay let me write answer for u..

Comment: yes please....i will be really thankful to you..

Comment: i am done writing answer try it and tell me it worked..lol.

Answer (score 0):

**Controller Code Explanation.**

```
<?php
    $data = $this->Question->findById($id);
```

**above will return all the question and associated answer array as below.**

```
Array
(
    [Question] => Array
    (
        [id] => 121
        [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
        [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
    )
    [Option] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 123
                [quesion_id] => 121
                [body] => The Kungwooness is not so Gwooish
                [created] => 2006-05-01 10:31:01
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 124
                [quesion_id] => 121
                [title] => More on Gwoo
                [created] => 2006-05-01 10:41:01
            )
    )
)
```

**Now, all we need to do is build our form (let's make something really simple):**

```
echo $form->create('Question', array('action' => 'edit'));
foreach($this->data['Option'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $form->input('Option.'.$key.'.name');
    echo $form->input('Option.'.$key.'.id');
}
echo $form->end('Save All');
```

It is built from our `$this->data` array and follows exactly the right format, which allows the `saveAll()` method to work correctly.

Now post it and see i am sure it will work now.

Cheers.

Comment: @user1990503 does it give you error...that must work because its the only way...let me know your model code and associations between them

Comment: no error...
in question model file...i applied has many relation and in option model i applied belongs to relation...

Comment: @user1990503 does form is creating perfectly..? also use this code to save all $this->Question->Option->saveAll($this->request->data['Option']);

Comment: this line of code is also adding the options and without question id even...question id is going 0 then,..

Comment: @user1990503 don't use foreach (range(0,2) as $index) instead use my code...and for question id you need to set $this->data['Option']['question_id'] = $this->data['Question']['id'];

Comment: still not happening..i am thankful to you that you are putting so much of efforts to help me..but don't know why i am not getting it right..:(