# saveAll() Failing with CakePHP 2.3.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am building a CakePHP 2.3 application, and can't for the life of me figure out why saveAll keeps failing.

I have the following models:

- `Artist` hasMany `ArtistPreview`
- `ArtistPreview` belongsTo `Artist`

I have no problem saving my `Artist` model with the `save()` function, however as soon as I try to use the `saveAll` method, Cake seems to fail validation - which is crazy because I have even totally removed all my validation rules from my models.

Here's my view, nothing crazy:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('Artist', array('inputDefaults' => array('class' => 'input-block-level')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Artist.name', array('label' => __('Name')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Artist.artist_section_id', array('label' => __('Section'), 'empty' => true));
?>
<label>Tags</label>
<div class="checkboxes">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Tag', array('label' => false, 'multiple' => 'checkbox', 'class' => false));; ?>
</div>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('Artist.website', array('label' => __('Website')));
    echo $this->Form->input('ArtistPreview.0.url', array('label' => __('Artist Preview')));
    echo $this->Form->input('Artist.description', array('label' => __('Description')));
?>
<?php

    echo $this->Form->submit(__('Add'), array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-large', 'div' => false)) . ' ';
    echo $this->Form->button(__('Cancel'), array('type' => 'button', 'class' => 'btn btn-large', 'div' => false, 'onclick' => 'closeDialog()'));
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

And here's my `add` controller method:

```
public function add() {
    $this->layout = 'form';

    if (!$this->request->is('ajax')) {
        throw new ForbiddenException();
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->setData($this->request->data['Artist'], array(
            'user_id' => AuthComponent::user('id'),
            'date' => $this->Date->gmt()
        ));
        if ($this->Artist->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->redirectAjax('/artists/view/' . $this->Artist->id);
        }
    }

    $this->set(array(
        'title_for_layout' => 'Add Artist',
        'artistSections' => $this->Artist->ArtistSection->find('list', array('order' => 'name')),
        'tags' => $this->Artist->Tag->find('list', array('order' => 'name'))
    ));
}
```

As I mentioned above, the saveAll method fails everytime. I have inspected what is getting output and Cake is outputting a bunch of blank `<div>`s with the `error-message` class, but there is no message. Every field on the form gets one of these divs.

Now, when I change my code to use the `save` function instead of `saveAll`, everything gets saved properly except the `ArtistPreview` data, which is to be expected. Even my HABTM Tags are being saved properly, and nothing fails validation.

I have been using Cake since the 1.3 days so I'm quite familiar with it, and have even done exactly what I'm asking in previous projects. I'm leaning towards this being a bug, unless I'm missing something here. Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**

I have also tried the `saveAssociated` method, along with setting the `deep` key to `true` when trying to save. This will let me save the artist, but it will not save the related data (ArtistPreview).

---

**EDIT 2**

As requested, here are the two tables:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `artists`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `artists` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artists` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `artist_section_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `artist_status_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(200) NULL ,
  `website` VARCHAR(500) NULL ,
  `description` TEXT NULL ,
  `date` DATETIME NULL ,
  `comment_count` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `FK_artists_users_idx` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `FK_artists__artist_sections_idx` (`artist_section_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `FK_artists__artist_statuses_idx` (`artist_status_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_artists__users`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id` )
    REFERENCES `users` (`id` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_artists__artist_sections`
    FOREIGN KEY (`artist_section_id` )
    REFERENCES `artist_sections` (`id` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_artists__artist_statuses`
    FOREIGN KEY (`artist_status_id` )
    REFERENCES `artist_statuses` (`id` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `artist_previews`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `artist_previews` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `artist_previews` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `artist_id` INT UNSIGNED NULL ,
  `url` VARCHAR(500) NULL ,
  `date` DATETIME NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `FK_artist_previews__artists_idx` (`artist_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_artist_previews__artists`
    FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id` )
    REFERENCES `artists` (`id` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Here is my `setData` function, which just merges two arrays. Instead of using hidden fields, I set fields in the controller which aren't populated by user input:

```
public function setData(&$original, $new) {
    $original = array_merge($original, $new);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not validating?  Have you tried manually validating via $this->Model->validate()?

Comment: There's no validation rules, so there should be nothing to validate! I can try `$this->Model->validate`, but I'll have to set the model data separately. When I pass the array with the `deep` key to the saveAll/saveAssociated methods, at least the artist gets saved. But it just doesn't want to save the related data. I'm going to perform a test with a clean install of Cake soon to see if it's a bug.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088608/update-multiple-model-through-a-single-form/15089414#15089414

Comment: Can you show the schema for the tables you are using? It might shed some light? Also, what does the function `$this->setData` do?

Comment: +1 because I learned a few things from looking at your code.

Comment: @ChuckBurgess I added the SQL for the two tables, as well as my code for the `setData` function. It just merges two arrays, so above it's setting `user_id` and `date` which aren't populated by the user.

Comment: Figured it out guys, rookie mistake. See answer below, thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: Also for the record, you do not need to add the relationship in the actual database. CakePHP will handle all of that in the ORM.

Comment: I know, but it helps keep things clean AND enforced. I'd much prefer to use MySQL's foreign key constraints than just relying on Cake alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finally figured this out, and wow was it a rookie mistake. I think I must've been half asleep yesterday when I was coding. The problem was in my model:

```
class Artist extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User',
        'ArtistSection',
        'ArtistStatus'
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'ArtistPicture',
        'Artist' // <--- problem was here, had 'Artist' instead of 'ArtistPreview'
    );

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Tag'
    );

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

        $this->validate = array(
            'name' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => __('Artist name cannot be blank.')
            ),
            'website' => array(
                'rule' => 'url',
                'message' => __('Must be a valid URL.'),
                'allowEmpty' => true
            ),
            'artist_section_id' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => __('Section is required.')
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you to those of you who took the time to look at this question, even though I posted the wrong information.